# r.in.gdal tries to create file in incorrect repository

Tags: gdal, grass-gis

I am trying to import a DEM in GTIFF format with:

```
r.in.gdal --overwrite input=$user_filename output=srtm_mosaik_utm -o
```

but I get the message:

```
Input contains an invalid SRS. WKT definition:
LOCAL_CS["Unknown",UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
ATTENTION: Unable to convert input map projection information to GRASS format.
Over-riding projection check
Importing raster map <srtm_mosaik_utm>...
ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `/home/d-name/d-name/eclipse-workspace/Detection/inputs/Artificial/srtm_mosaik_utm' failed: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (No file or repository of this type)
ERREUR :Impossible de créer le jeu de données <srtm_mosaik_utm> avec le pilote <GTiff>
```

Which is logical since the directory path '/home/d-name/d-name/eclipse-workspace/Detection/inputs/Artificial/' is incorrect (should be '/home/d-name/eclipse-workspace/Detection/inputs/Artificial/').

However, I don't understand how I can modify this output path? 
I must have changed it since it worked before.

Comment: To me it looks like broken metadata: LOCAL_CS["Unknown"... cannot be deciphered, hence subsequent errors occur. At time QGIS-GRASS try to process it as XY-data which eventually fails. Which coordinate system is it really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a grep on my computer and found a file named 'GDAL' in the 'PERMANENT' working repository I use for GRASS. The file had inside:

```
directory: /home/d-name/d-name/eclipse-workspace/Detection/inputs/Artificial
format: GTiff
```

I changed the directory path and it now works. I tested and supressing the file also works. I assume those are environment variables I set without realizing...

Comment: THis doesn't make any sense to me. Can you post the output of `g.gisenv` ? and what does `echo $user_filename` give??

Comment: Now I have this with g.gisenv: LOCATION_NAME=grassdata
GISDBASE=/home/d-name/Documents
MAPSET=PERMANENT
GUI=text
PID=8461 and nothing in $user_filename.

Answer (score 2):

First, normally the directory "Documents" probably contains lots of files that have nothing to do with GRASS. It's NOT a good idea to have your GRASS gisdbase mixed with other stuff. I suggest you reset your GRASS database. Typically you would have a dedicated directory called "grassdata" or similar. You can either directly edit the .grass7/rc file to point to this directory, or just reset the grassdata in the wizard when you first start GRASS.

Next, if the variable $user_filename does not contain the full path to the tiff you are importing, then what command are you actually running? It should be something like:

```
r.in.gdal -o input=/full/path/to/dem.tif output=strm_mosaic
```

Comment: Yes, $user_filename contains "DEM.tif" without the path, because DEM.tif is in the same repository as the script file.

Answer (score 0):

If time allows and your files are not huge in size, probably worth setting a fresh grassdata folder as GISDBASE. You might want to recheck if this works:

1. Check which CRS is your original DEM. Open and check the properties in QGIS for a quick check/ use gdalinfo at the command prompt pointing to the DEM something like `gdalinfo full/path/to/DEM.tif`
2. Open a new GRASS session and use the setup wizard to set the GISDBASE and LOCATION name using the CRS/ Projection you found in the above step. You can use Micha's help above.
3. Now import the DEM (assuming you are happy with the current SRS of the DEM) using `r.import` or `r.in.gdal` either from GRASS commandline as Micha advised or using GUI from File> Import Raster Data.
4. If you want to consult graphical step by step guide, you can look at the '[Graphical Startup of GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/helptext.html)'

Comment: There is no CRS in my original DEM, because it's an artificial one I created myself and then converted using GMT to a gTiff format without specifying a CRS. The importing was ok, it's the outputing that was not.